# Can I change the scope of product's "status" attribute to store level?

Tags: product, attributes, product-attribute, scope

In magento backend you only have the choice between global and website scopes for the "status" attribute of a product. Can it be changed to the store level, so that different stores have different products activated? Will it have any side effects or is there another reason why it's not allowed to be on the store level by default?

Comment: I think there is a logic behind having the status on website level (not sure though). My opinion is to not interfere with this logic. If you want a product to not be shown on a specific store view, you can change it's visibility. Set it to 'Not visible individually'. The Visibility attribute has the scope 'store_view' so this should work.

Comment: Did you try my method bellow?

Answer (score 5):

To hide products on different stores, normally the Visibility is used which works on store level.

I don't think it is a good idea to change the status scope to storeview, because indexing and other things are working with this value.

Answer (score 0):

The **Status** attribute is to conveniently Disable or Enable products without deleting them. 
If you have a requirement to have select products appear in specific store views, you need to assign the products to those store views.

If you want to Enable or Disable products across individual stores / views you need to modify the product at the products store view level:

1. Catalog --> Manage Products
2. The default store view should be "All Store Views"
3. Click on the product you wish to assign
4. Select the product Select "Websites" on the left
5. Place a check mark in the store view you wish the product to appear
6. Click  "Save and Continue Edit"
7. Click "General" From the "Choose Store View:" drop
   down, select the store / view you assigned the product.
8. Scroll down to the "Status" attribute, notice the "Use Default Value" is checked.
9. Deselect this value
10. Set the "Status" to Enabled or Disabled
11. Click Save

This will achieve what you are looking for.

NOTE: You can assign multiple products and Enable / Disable using the same principles with the "Actions" ---> "Update Attributes"  tool on the "Manage Products" page.

Comment: I fear it would not work this way, since you can only assign products on the website level and not on the store level.

Comment: Yes you can assign products at the store level, I will elaborate.

Comment: will this works ?

Comment: Products can only be assigned to Websites, not to Stores or Store Views. This method isn't what the original poster is looking for.

Comment: @TylerV. wow right on time!

Answer (score 0):

I once stuck in the same issue. Whenever I tried changing status attribute value on a single store, it was getting change in the other store as well which was not required. 
Than I changed the **is_global** column for the **status** attribute in **catalog_eav_attribute** table and boom.